# Most efficient way to calculate number of iterations to run

Tags: loops

Let's say I have a batch process that executes 4 times per loop, and needs to execute a total of 9 items.

Example:

- Iteration 1 executes 4 items of 9, leaving 5 left
- Iteration 2 executes 4 times of 9, leaving 1 left
- Iteration 3 only executes 1 item because that's all that is left.

Currently I handle it with a modulus operation:

```
$number_of_items = 9
$number_of_executions_per_loop = 4

For $iteration = 1 to $number_of_items Step $number_of_executions_per_loop
   If $number_of_items < ($iteration * $number_of_executions_per_loop) Then
      $iteration_execution_count = MOD($number_of_items,$number_of_executions_per_loop)
   Else
      $iteration_execution_count = $number_of_executions_per_loop
   EndIf

   ExecuteJobsFunction($iteration_execution_count)

Next
```

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to handle these types of scenarios that I see frequently. Is there a math trick that can be done to determine how many items to execute?

Comment: `(n+k-1)/k` where `/` is integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the dollar signs sprinkled in your code, you appear to be using some extremely high level and possibly highly inefficient script, so taking a `MOD()` is probably the least of your concerns, and what you do is just fine.

But if you *really really* want to simplify it, then you might want to consider something like the following:

```
number_of_items = 9
number_of_executions_per_loop = 4

For iteration = 1 to number_of_items Step number_of_executions_per_loop
   iteration_execution_count = number_of_executions_per_loop
   If iteration_execution_count > number_of_items - iteration Then
      iteration_execution_count = number_of_items - iteration
   EndIf

   ExecuteJobsFunction(iteration_execution_count)

Next
```